# Error to execute TestNG tests,Cucumver scenarioes with WebDriver using Gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle, webdriver, cucumber

I am trying to run testNG tests, cucumber scenarios using Gradle.[this is my build script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT4cq.png)

while executing command "grdale test" from Jenkins pipeline ,getting an error-[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSkrQ.png)

I suspect with WebDriver is not getting invoked is the issue and finding solution.

Comment: Can you please show us what your `test/index.html` looks like ?

Comment: Thanks Krishnan, but this project is executing on Jenkins master machine and  don't have privileges to browse this file.so I have checked with it's HTML content , VALUE for tests -1,failure -1 and ignored - 0.

Comment: Some element cannot be found - NoSuchElementException is there in the error file. Locator is not correct or you have a timing issue. You will need a better stacktrace to find out which code line is failing.

Comment: @DarshanaPatel - If you are referring to a suite xml file, then you could bump up its log levels through `verbose` attribute of the `<suite>` tag, download the reports to your local desktop from your Jenkins workspace to check for the cause of the error.

Comment: Error- cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: by.xpath....